# AvailableOpenshift current (3.11) open source APM solutions

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, apm, okd, hawkular

It seems that Hawkular APM is not actively maintained anymore (https://www.hawkular.org/hawkular-apm/).

What opensource APM solutions do we have currently available for Openshift Container Platform?

Can you detail the features they provide (application metrics -CPU, memory...-, application support -polyglot, container based...-, distributed tracing, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hawkular` will be replaced with `Prometheus` from `v4.x+`, refer the [release notes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/release_notes/ocp_3_11_release_notes.html#ocp-311-major-changes-in-40) for more informations.
As far as I know, each feature in charge of component list is as follows.
Basically the component is provided as [Operator](https://coreos.com/operators/) in the future.

- Resource Monitoring: [Prometheus Operator](https://operatorhub.io/operator/prometheusoperator-community.0.22.2)
- Distributed tracing: [Jaeger Tracing](https://operatorhub.io/operator/jaeger-operator.v1.8.2)
- Application Performance Monitoring: [Dynatrace OneAgent](https://operatorhub.io/operator/dynatrace-monitoring.v0.2.0)

You can get the details of each page of the components from [OperatorHub.io](https://operatorhub.io/). I hope it help you.